# what is a good way for an app to know if tcp keep alive failed?

Tags: sockets, tcp, keep-alive

I have a client-server app where both communicate over tcp. We are planning on reusing the tcp in-built keep alive mechanism to ensure both client and server know the other guy is alive.

A few questions:

1. Right now, we have done a setsockopt(..) to enable tcp keep alive and also have set the keep alive timeout values. Lets assume the application is idle. I want the application to know that the keep alive timed out ...which means the client-server connection is down. The app then has to display an error page. What is a good way for the application to know that? I believe if a tcp keep alive times out, subsequent attempts to send a msg over that socket will return a WSAENETRESET error, but I want the app to know even if it is idle and no messages are flowing.

I was thinking of doing the following:
Have a loop that runs every 20s (duration may be increased/decreased) and does a setsockopt to set the keep alive to true. If the connection is broken, this call will return a WSAENETRESET error.

1. What would be a good keep alive interval to use?
2. Any issues with using the tcp in built keep alive mechanism?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special you need to do. Presumably, you are already trying to read from the socket or appropriately waiting for it to become ready to read. If the connection fails, it will be ready to read (since you can no longer wait for it to become ready to read), and your read attempt will get an error.

Comment: You mean have a blocking recv call that would normally read data, but if keep alive times out, it would return a WSAENETRESET error.

Comment: @techieChamp If that's how you receive data, then yes. If you receive data some other way, then whatever that other way is. Presumably, you already have some mechanism to receive data from the connection, whether it's `poll`, `select`, overlapped I/O, a blocking read, or whatever.

Comment: right now, we are using a send followed by recv. we were all along still doing prototype work, but will be rearranging it to have recv as a separate call on a different thread.

Comment: @techieChamp If you know for a fact that the other side will not send first, then you may have to use an uglyish hack. One option is `getpeername`, another is `getsockopt(SO_ERROR)`.

Comment: If you can, implement an explicit keepalive message into your communication protocol, don't rely on TCP keepalive by itself. That way, the client and server can periodically say "I'm still here" to each other at regular intervals (the interval of the TCP keepalive cannot be configured on some platforms). If either one does not receive such a message after a period of time, just assume the connection is dead and close it, regardless of what the TCP keepalive says.

Comment: @RemyLebeau To add to what Remy said, TCP keepalive is really intended to help legacy applications that weren't designed to work with TCP (they were designed to work over generic pipes or streams). Keepalives are an awkward solution and should only be used when the protocol provides no way to support detecting a lost connection and it cannot be changed or where the applications cannot be changed for some reason.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, David Schwartz: Thanks for your comments. this is the info I was also looking for. what are the disadvantages or issues while using tcp keep alive? I am basically trying to make a decision whether to go ahead with tcp keep alive or define my own. The in-built tcp keep alive one seems attractive since it needs minimal coding effort. I will take a look at the tcp rfc and other content to understand this better, but basically want to come up with one strong reason to go thru the exercise of defining an application level keep-alive. Thanks once again...

Comment: @techieChamp One is that you have no control over keep alive timing. You get what's built into the OS. Another is that it only confirms the TCP connection is still alive, the application on the other end can be dead.

Comment: On a similar note - tcp also supports timeouts and retry options. Can we reuse them or does it make sense to define that at the application level itself? I agree that defining these values at the app layer will ensure that issues at the app layer at either end can also be handled.

Comment: @techieChamp If you're using TCP, you are using its timeouts and retry logic. So long as you try to send something, that send will be retried until it times out, at which time an error will be generated.

Comment: Cool..thanks. In other words, no need to add a app layer keep-alive?

Comment: @techieChamp It depends how you think about. You probably don't need an app layer keep-alive so long as your app sends data from time to time, because the send will time out if the connection becomes unusable. But one can argue that that's an app layer keep-alive. Put another way, in a typical app layer keep-alive scheme, it's the fact that you're sending periodically that does the keeping alive, not the receiving and checking.

Answer (score 0):

About the way of checking keep alive:

If the program is blocked reading the stream and keep alive fails it will be interrupted with an error. If your program doesn't need to wait for incoming messages you can spawn a thread that does that.

Another question is if you really need to check every 20 seconds or you can just check when you need to send a message.

If find keep alive particularly useful at server side, where the program waits for messages, because otherwise the server would never know that the connection is broken and will be waiting for incoming messages for ever (wasting threads and ports).

About your questions:

1. Default value is usually 2 hours, these are lightweight packets so you could keep it much lower, but I wouldn't use a value lower than a minute unless it's really necessary.
2. No that I'm aware of.